# Notation: minimum for all (sub) elements

Tags: soft-question, maxima-minima

Have an element list `\Delta`, these Elements have sub values, `\alpha`, `\beta`, `\gamma`.
I want to write:
the minimum from the sub element `\alpha`, over all elements `\Delta`.

How can I write this mathematically correct (in latex)?

```
\min ...
```

thx

Comment: Assuming $\Delta$ consists of triples $(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$, you could do something like $\displaystyle\min_{(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)\in\Delta}\alpha$.

Comment: Thanks @Lorago Can I write it differently if there are too many variables in `\Delta` that don't all fit under min? The minimal element is only about the `\alpha` from `\Delta`.

Comment: How about $\displaystyle\min_{S\in\Delta}S_\alpha$, using subscript to denote the subvariables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key part is to just be clear about what you mean. Since it's not clear what exactly $\Delta$ consists of, suppose $\Delta$ is some arbitrary collection of elements $S$, where we use $S_\alpha$ to denote the $\alpha$-component of $S$. Then we could write

$$\min_{S\in\Delta}S_\alpha$$

to denote the minimum of all $\alpha$'s. Another approach (which I do not like as much, but still works), would be to define a function

$$\phi:\Delta\to\mathbb{R},\quad S\mapsto S_\alpha,$$

i.e. $\phi(S)$ is the $\alpha$-value of $S\in\Delta$. We could then write

$$\min_{S\in\Delta}\phi(S).$$

Of course there are other ways to do it as well; the most important part is to be clear.